# Why doesn't AllegroGraph parse my file?

Tags: rdf

I am trying to import a RDF file into an AllegroGraph tripple-store, but i keep getting this error:

```
Import failed: MALFORMED DATA: [in Sax parser] 
parse of #<file-simple-stream #P"/tmp/agwebview-upload-EoncCgvalid.xml" 
for input pos 3 @ #x100413feb2> failed filename nil, position 1
```

My file, called "valid.xml", should be valid, since it comes from http://rdf.freebase.com/rdf/venture_capital.views.investment_round
and I have added this at its beginning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.my.com/site"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.my.com/xhtml" xmlns:cc="http://www.my.com/cc">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have you added that to the beginning? It already starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#"
>
```

so your addition will break the file.

To see this try, for example:

```
$ curl -s http://rdf.freebase.com/rdf/venture_capital.views.investment_round | head
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#"
>
  <fb:common.document rdf:about="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/venture_capital.views.investment_round">
    <cc:attributionName>Source: Freebase - The World's database</cc:attributionName>
    <xhtml:license rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/"/>
```

Or even better the [W3C RDF validation service](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/): [Validate the freebase data](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/ARPServlet?URI=http%3A%2F%2Frdf.freebase.com%2Frdf%2Fventure_capital.views.investment_round+&PARSE=Parse+URI%3A+&TRIPLES_AND_GRAPH=PRINT_TRIPLES&FORMAT=PNG_EMBED)

Comment: I don't understad... where have you seen that? I've followed the link and what I saw began with <rdf:RDF>. What you are saying might be important, so please reply.

Comment: What are you viewing it with? I think it's misleading you. Added a couple of ways to check the existing data to my answer.

Comment: I have found my mistake: I wasn't saving the page, I was just copying what Firefox was showing me... Thanks!

Comment: Is firefox still losing namespace information? That's been broken for such a long time. Glad you've sorted it out.

Comment: Why do you even copy-paste the file? Just load the RDF directly into your triplestore using the URL. Most triplestores support this...

Answer (score 1):

The file as hosted on the freebase site is valid, you don't need to change it.

You can confirm this with the tool "rapper":

> $ rapper -c -i rdfxml http://rdf.freebase.com/rdf/venture_capital.views.investment_round
>   rapper: Parsing URI http://rdf.freebase.com/rdf/venture_capital.views.investment_round with parser rdfxml
>   rapper: Parsing returned 16 triples